# Как отсортировать и склеить матрицу (список списков)

Tags: python, алгоритм, список

Данные для каждого исходного списка читаются из некоторых файлов:

```
my_list1 = [[4, 5, 6], [34, 64, 23], [25, 65, 65]]
my_list2 = [[1, 2, 3], [24, 74, 23], [41, 98, 12]]
my_list3 = [[7, 8, 9], [25, 88, 21], [56, 34, 87]]
```

Есть ли возможность 'склеить' данные на чистом python, одновременно отсортировав по первому элементу последовательностей, без привлечения сторонних модулей (numpy, например), чтобы получить вот такой результат?

```
result = [[1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
          [24, 74, 23, 34, 64, 23, 25, 88, 21],
          [41, 98, 12, 25, 65, 65, 56, 34, 87]]
```

Открывая исходные данные как массивы numpy:
result = numpy.hstack((my_list1, my_list2, my_list3)) справляется со склеиванием, но не сортирует по первому элементу

Comment: Опишите подробнее, как конкретно вы хотите сортировать списки. Единственный способ, который пришёл мне в голову не подтверждается третей строкой (25 < 41, но стоит во второй тройке, а не в первой).

Comment: Данные в исходных списках, кроме первой позиции, произвольные. Numpy склеивает как надо, но не сортирует по первым элементам: [[ 4  5  6  1  2  3  7  8  9]
 [34 64 23 24 74 23 25 88 21]
 [25 65 65 41 98 12 56 34 87]]
<class 'numpy.int64'>

Comment: Ваш пример результата, который вы хотите увидеть, не подходит под ваше описание сортировки. Стоит уточнить критерий сортировки или исправить желаемый вид результата.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Мне больше понравилось `solution_2` – нагляднее и короче получилось, хоть и решение в лоб:

```
import itertools


def solution_0(*args):
    matrix = sorted(args, key=lambda x: x[0])

    N = len(matrix)
    M = len(matrix[0])

    return [
        list(itertools.chain(*[matrix[j][i] for j in range(M)]))
        for i in range(N)
    ]


def solution_1(*args):
    matrix = sorted(args, key=lambda x: x[0])

    new_matrix = list()
    
    N = len(matrix)
    M = len(matrix[0])

    for i in range(N):
        row = list()

        for j in range(M):
            row += matrix[j][i]

        new_matrix.append(row)

    return new_matrix


def solution_2(my_list1, my_list2, my_list3):
    matrix = [my_list1] + [my_list2] + [my_list3]
    matrix.sort(key=lambda x: x[0])

    return [
        matrix[0][0] + matrix[1][0] + matrix[2][0],
        matrix[0][1] + matrix[1][1] + matrix[2][1],
        matrix[0][2] + matrix[1][2] + matrix[2][2],
    ]


my_list1 = [[4, 5, 6], [34, 64, 23], [25, 65, 65]]
my_list2 = [[1, 2, 3], [24, 74, 23], [41, 98, 12]]
my_list3 = [[7, 8, 9], [25, 88, 21], [56, 34, 87]]

result = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
          [24, 74, 23, 34, 64, 23, 25, 88, 21],
          [41, 98, 12, 25, 65, 65, 56, 34, 87]]

print(result == solution_0(my_list1, my_list2, my_list3))  # True
print(result == solution_1(my_list1, my_list2, my_list3))  # True
print(result == solution_2(my_list1, my_list2, my_list3))  # True
```

**UPDATE**. Добавил `solution_0` – тот же `solution_1`, но более `pythonic way`

Comment: Да, это, конечно, работает. Главный вопрос - как это все в циклы и организовать. Количество исходных списков и количество элементов в них может варьироваться - как избежать явного указания индексов. PS: Спасибо за сортировку с lambda.

Comment: Ну, `solution_1` с циклами работает

Comment: Обновил `solution_1`, теперь ему можно сколько угодно передавать списков -- склеивание и подсчет размера он сам сделает

Comment: Спасибо, работает! Сейчас попробую разобраться.

Comment: Надо, только, ввести проверку. Матрица может быть не равносторонней. С этим я, наверное, справлюсь.

Comment: Тогда, это не будет матрицей :) Я думал об этом, тогда нужно `M` на каждой итерации первого цикла определять, что-то вроде такого: `M = len(matrix[i])`

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы получить желаемый результат, необходимо *транспонировать* матрицу, затем отсортировать вложенные списки в каждой строке по желаемому критерию, а затем объединить отсортированные списки в каждой строке:

```
>>> a = [[4, 5, 6], [34, 64, 23], [25, 65, 65]]
>>> b = [[1, 2, 3], [24, 74, 23], [41, 98, 12]]
>>> c = [[7, 8, 9], [25, 88, 21], [56, 34, 87]]
>>> [[x for lst in sorted(row) for x in lst] for row in zip(a, b, c)]
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
 [24, 74, 23, 25, 88, 21, 34, 64, 23],
 [25, 65, 65, 41, 98, 12, 56, 34, 87]]
```

[`zip(a, b, c)` транспонирует матрицу](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4937491/4279), состоящую из строк `a`, `b`, `c`.

`sorted(row)` сортирует списки в каждой строке. Не ясно какой критерий для сортировки использует `result` в вопросе, поэтому я оставил сортировку по умолчанию (`[25, 88, 21] < [34, 64, 23]`). Можно явно передать `key` параметр в `sorted()`, чтобы поменять поведение.

Вложенное list comprehension используется, чтобы «склеить» списки в каждой строке матрицы. See [Flattening a shallow list in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/406121/4279).